# Can you interpolate ruby variables within HAML css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, haml, interpolation

I need a series of classes, .module1, .module2, ... module(n).

I also want to define those classes using css, ruby and HAML:

```
:css
  .mod1 {
        background-image: url("#{extra.image}");
    }
```

Is it possible to interpolate ruby variables to save work?

```
.module.mod"#{extra.id}"
  %h3 #{extra.title}
  %p #{extra.description}
  %a.btn-default{:href => "#", :target => "_top"} enter now

:css
  .mod#{extra.id} {
        background-image: url("#{extra.image}");
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [HAML_REFERENCE](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#css-filter) I used this method:

```
- flavor = "raspberry"
#content
  :textile
    I *really* prefer _#{h flavor}_ jam.
```

to interpolate variables after :css

```
.module.modone{:class => "#{cycle("mod_#{extra.id}_")}"}

  %h3 #{extra.title}
  %p #{extra.description}
  %a.btn-default{:href => "#", :target => "_top"} enter now

:css
  .mod_#{extra.id}_ { 
    background-image: url("#{extra.image}");
    background-color: #4073DF;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:css
  .mod_#{extra.id}_ { 
    background-image: url("#{extra.image}");
    height: #{ruby_height}#{measure_unit_ruby_variable};
  }
```