# How do I successfully interpolate Ruby inside the CSS attribute of a HAML %li HTML tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, haml, erb, interpolation

Long time listener, first time caller. I'm a 6 month old dev from Code Academy here in Chicago, and I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours. Beforehand, I appreciate all of your assistance and time.

I'm converting an ERB template to HAML. The ERB is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-header">
    <%= navigation_header %>
  </li>
  <% @navigation_links.each do |link| %>
  <% if link[:name].present? %>
    <li <%= link[:name] == @topic ? "class='active'" : "" %>>
      <%= link_to link[:name], link[:url] %>
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <hr />
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The ERB line I'm having trouble with is:

```
<li <%= link[:name] == @topic ? "class='active'" : "" %>>
```

I've tested many variations, read as much of the HAML reference as possible, concentrating on [this](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#attributes) section:

> You can also use #{} interpolation to insert complicated expressions
>   in a HTML-style attribute:

```
%span(class="widget_#{@widget.number}")
```

...and searched Google & [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656915/can-you-interpolate-ruby-variables-within-haml-css), but I cannot get the output correct; HAML keeps disregarding the inline CSS. After all my groundwork, I was so confident in this version, but it didn't work:

```
- @navigation_links.each do |link|
  - if link[:name].present?
    %li{ :class => "#{ link[:name] == @topic ? "active" : ""}" }
      = link_to link[:name], link[:url]
  - else
    %hr
```

I've also tried an :erb filter, to no avail:

```
%ul.nav.nav-list
  %li.nav-header
    = navigation_header
- @navigation_links.each do |link|
  - if link[:name].present?
    :erb
      <li <%= link[:name] == @topic ? "class='active'" : "" %>>
    = link_to link[:name], link[:url]
  - else
    %hr
```

And I've also tried a :css filter, but that failed.

Any ideas what could be wrong? This is my first question on StackOverflow, so if I omitted some helpful info or broke any rules, please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<li <%= link[:name] == @topic ? "class='active'" : "" %>>
```

You don't need variable interpolation. This translates rather easily into HAML as either of the following:

```
%li{:class => (link[:name] == @topic) && "active"}
%li{:class => (link[:name] == @topic) ? "active" : "" }
```

The first is preferred in cases where you are including or omitting the value altogether. From the [HAML docs](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#class-and-id-attributes):

> If a single value is specified and it evaluates to false it is
>   ignored; otherwise it gets converted to a string. For example:
>
> ```
> .item{:class => @item.is_empty? && "empty"}
> ```

Comment: Not sure how to award points etc. The reason my CSS was not displaying the active class was primarily because my each loop was not indented enough to catch two classes from above it. Would my interpolation version still have worked, or was your syntax _required_? I do want to give you credit for suggesting and educated me on the && operator!

Comment: Your syntax was fine, but less than ideal.